# Is SplittableRandom.split() threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, random, thread-safety

I am working on a web application where I need to generate a random number for each request. The request will hit a specific bucket from a set of buckets. The random numbers generated for a given bucket should have a uniform distribution. I am planning to use a map which has a SplittableRandom instances against bucket ids like this

buketId ->  SplittableRandom

To entertain a web-request I first check the bucketId specified in the request. Then I select the corresponding SplittableRandom instance and call split() on it. Under heavy load split() method will be called on the same instance by multiple threads. Is this approach thread safe?

Comment: No. Either create fresh instances locally or use a regular `Random`.

Answer (score 4):

From the javadoc

> Instances of SplittableRandom are *not* thread-safe. They are
>   designed to be split, not shared, across threads. For example, a
>   `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask` fork/join-style computation
>   using random numbers might include a construction of the form 
>   `new Subtask(aSplittableRandom.split()).fork()`.

The `split()` method returns a new instance of `SplittableRandom` based on `this`.

```
public SplittableRandom split() {
    return new SplittableRandom(nextLong(), mixGamma(nextSeed()));
}
```

The `mixGamma()` method is thread-safe, but calls to `nextSeed()` (both in `split()` and `nextLong()`) are not, since they modify the non-volatile `long seed` without any synchronization mechanism.

Comment: @shmosel You're right, it's not (when you go down to `nextSeed()`).